# WooCommerce use Country and Postcode for shipping estimate in custom method

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to force shipping estimate to use postcode and country. I am building a custom shipping method (similar to tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098)). I can get both the country and postcode values fine. However, only country seems to be required by default, and postcode is optional with the field even greyed. Here is an [example image of Change Address fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBdBE.png). My shipping method breaks when the postcode is empty as in the example image. How do I require both country and postcode? Note - State and city are not required in my custom method.

Comment: You need to provide the code that you are using in your question…

Comment: The code is just like in [the tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098) I linked to. The only difference is in `calculate_shipping()` I changed `$country = $package["destination"]["country"];` to `$country = $package["destination"]["postcode"];` and update `$cost` based on postcode value. The cost only gets updated if a postcode is set. How do I require it?